# I am terribly lost with this SQL project. Sales Order for a burger joint

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

So I'm taking this SQL class in college and I am just lost. I need to make a sales order DB that displays items sold, guest id, address, price, etc...

Now, this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8pLr.png) is what I have so far:

```
create table buyer (Guest int not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

buyer_first_name varchar(30) not null,

buyer_middle_name varchar(30) not null,

buyer_last_name varchar(30) not null,

address_street varchar(50) not null,

address_apt_num varchar(100) not null,

phone_home varchar(15) not null,

phone_mobile varchar(15) not null,

email varchar(50),

PRIMARY KEY (Guest));

create table item (ProductID int not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

PerUnit varchar(50) not null,

Product varchar(50) not null,

Details varchar(200),

PRIMARY KEY (ProductID));

create table sales_order (OrderID int not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

Guest int not null,

Date varchar(20),

SpecialInstructions varchar(200),

PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),

FOREIGN KEY (Guest) REFERENCES buyer(Guest)

)ENGINE=INNODB;

create table order_line (OrderID int not null,

ProductID int not null,

Amount int,

PRIMARY KEY (OrderID,ProductID),

FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES sales_order(OrderID),

FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES item(ProductID)

)ENGINE=INNODB;

insert into buyer(buyer_first_name,

buyer_middle_name ,

buyer_last_name ,

address_street ,

address_apt_num ,

phone_home ,

phone_mobile ,

email) values ('Naruto','Ninja','Uzumaki','1234 HokageDrive','1A', '1234567890', '1233126540','naruto@hotmail.com');

INSERT INTO item(Product,Details,PerUnit)

VALUES

('Big Burger Deluxe','Single Patty with Cheese','$1.99'),

('Double Big','2 Patties on a Bun','$2.99'),

('Happy Size Fries','10oz Fries w/ Seasoning','$0.99'),

('Chocolate Shake','Thick Chocolate Shake','$1.49'),

('Strawberry Shake','Thick Strawberry Shake','$1.49'),

('Cherry Pie','Deep-fried cherry Pie with Cream Cheese Icing.','$1.29');

INSERT INTO sales_order(SpecialInstructions,Guest,Date)

VALUES

('Please double bag the order.',1,'Sept. 2, 2015');

INSERT INTO order_line(OrderID,ProductID,Amount) VALUES (1,1,2);
```

Now I'm terrible with SQL and would like friendly 'Nudge' into the correct direction. I really do love doing this stuff! :)

When I run:

```
select * from buyer a

join sales_order b on

a.Guest=b.Guest

join order_line c on

b.OrderID=c.OrderID

Join item d on

c.ProductID=d.ProductID
```

I do not get the expected output of something along these lines:https://ibb.co/h0nP9J (without line totals)

Where can I start?

P.S. I'm using SQL Fiddle for this assignment.

UPDATE:
**My Instructions:** Provide the SQL code for a complex join query to display all of the information contained in the attached “Receipt” with the
exception of the calculated attributes (Line Total, Subtotal,
Sales Tax and Total).

So from what I understand they want all the information at 1 time? I'll request clarification form instructors.
**Expected Output:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXKLs.png)

```
Guest ID    Order ID    FN  MI  LN  Address APT#    Home    Cell    Email   Product ID  Per/Unit    Product Details Amount
1   1   Naruto  Ninja   Uzumaki 1234 Hokage Dr  1A  123 123 narutouzumaki@hotmail.com   1   1.99    Big Burger Deluxe   Single patty with Cheese    2
1   1   Naruto  Ninja   Uzumaki 1234 Hokage Dr  1A  123 123 narutouzumaki@hotmail.com   2   2.99    Double Big  2 Patties on a Bun  2
1   1   Naruto  Ninja   Uzumaki 1234 Hokage Dr  1A  123 123 narutouzumaki@hotmail.com   3   0.99    Happy Size Fries    10oz Fries w/ Seasoning 4
1   1   Naruto  Ninja   Uzumaki 1234 Hokage Dr  1A  123 123 narutouzumaki@hotmail.com   4   1.49    Chocolate Shake Thick Chocolate Shake   1
1   1   Naruto  Ninja   Uzumaki 1234 Hokage Dr  1A  123 123 narutouzumaki@hotmail.com   5   1.49    Strawberry Shake    Thick Strawberry Shake  3
1   1   Naruto  Ninja   Uzumaki 1234 Hokage Dr  1A  123 123 narutouzumaki@hotmail.com   6   1.29    Cherry Pie  Deep-fried cherry Pie with Cream Cheese Icing.  2
```

******Follow link [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXKLs.png) for what I believe is the expected output.**
**UPDATE**

My data was fine and I was able to get that working with an inner join query!

```
select
b.Guest,
b.buyer_first_name,
b.buyer_middle_name,
b.buyer_last_name,
b.address_street,
b.address_apt_num,
b.phone_home,
b.phone_mobile,
b.email,
s.OrderID,
s.`Date`,
o.ProductID,
i.PerUnit,
i.Product,
i.Details,
s.SpecialInstructions,
o.Amount
from buyer b
inner join sales_order s on b.Guest = s.Guest
inner join order_line o on s.OrderID = o.OrderID
inner join item i on o.ProductID = i.ProductID;
```

Comment: Try and use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default and only restrict that if you have a very compelling reason. For many things, like email addresses, shorter fields can cause huge hassles for your users.

Comment: "I'm using SQL Fiddle for this assignment." Prove it!

Comment: Also, you're conflating two problems here: issues of data retrieval, and issues of data display. Keep them separate, and ignore the display issues for now. Amend your question to show your desired result.

Comment: Please embed your expected output in the *body* of the question.  You can *also* include a link, but all necessary info needs to be here: 1) the link could become unavailable, thus render this SO page useless 2) People do not want to click over the web just to figure out your question. Please `edit` to update your question with code, bringing it up to SO site guidelines.  All the Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Took the time to play with it on DB-Fiddle;

The data itself is fine, it's the select statement that's going to give you grief.

Your current statement is SELECT * with a join on several tables, that means that it will pull all the columns from all the tables. Looking at the example image you've provided, you don't need to present everything in one query.

For instance, the order grid doesn't require buyer_first_name, but the select statement includes it, whereas the Guest information doesn't require PerUnit from the item table. If I were you, I'd break the SELECT * statement into several smaller ones where you specify explicitly what columns you want to include.

As an aside: "INNER JOIN" is clearer to read than "JOIN" especially since they mean the same thing and you'll likely need to be able to easily differentiate the various types of JOIN queries. Likewise, buyer.buyer_middle_name probably shouldn't be set to NOT NULL. not everyone has a middle name. Same thing with AptNumber.

Hopefully this sets you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can get all the information separately but from what my instructions say, I need a complex join query to gather all data at once. I'm going to confirm with my instructors though.

Comment: I figured it out with the inner join! Thanks for your help! I will edit above.

Comment: If you feel this is the correct answer, please mark it as so